# Why these SQL code keeps showing error of IDENTIFIER TOO LONG?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table EMPLOYEE
(Emp_id VARCHAR(30) not null,
Emp_fname varchar(20),
Emp_mname varchar(20),
Emp_lname varchar(20),
Emp_SSN varchar(20),
"position" varchar(30),
Emp_Straddr1 varchar(100),
Emp_Straddr2 varchar(100),
Emp_City varchar(100),
Emp_State varchar(100),
Emp_Zip char(5),
Emp_Phone varchar(20),
Supervisor VARCHAR(30) not null,
constraint pk_employee primary key (Emp_id),
constraint fk_employeehassupervisor foreign key (Supervisor)     references EMPLOYEE(Emp_id));

create table VINEYARD
(Vineyard_Name VARCHAR(20) not null,
"Location" varchar(30),
"Size" number(4,2),
Emp_id VARCHAR(5) not null,
constraint pk_vineyard primary key (Vineyard_Name),
constraint fk_vineyardhasmanager foreign key (Emp_id) references EMPLOYEE(Emp_id));

create table GRAPE
(Grape_Name varchar(30) not null,
JuiceConversionRatio number(5,2),
WineStorageRequirement varchar(30),
WineAgingRequirement varchar(1),
constraint pk_grape primary key (Grape_Name));



alter table VINEYARD 
modify (Vineyard_Name VARCHAR(20));

create table GRAPE_HARVEST_HISTORY
(Vineyard_Name varchar(20) not null,
Grape_Name varchar(30) not null,
"Year" YEAR NOT NULL,
Weight number(4,2),
RipenessDegree number(5,2),
constraint pk_grape_harvest_history primary key      (Vineyard_Name,"Year"),
constraint fk_grape_harvest_historyhasvineyard foreign key     (Vineyard_Name) references VINEYARD(Vineyard_Name),
constraint fk_grape_harvest_historyhasgrape foreign key (Grape_Name)      references GRAPE(Grape_Name));
```

---

down here is what exactly shown in ORACLE SQL.

Table EMPLOYEE created.

Table VINEYARD created.

Table GRAPE created.

Table VINEYARD altered.

Error starting at line : 38 in command -
create table GRAPE_HARVEST_HISTORY
(Vineyard_Name varchar(20) not null,
Grape_Name varchar(30) not null,
"Year" YEAR NOT NULL,
Weight number(4,2),
RipenessDegree number(5,2),
constraint pk_grape_harvest_history primary key (Vineyard_Name,"Year"),
constraint fk_grape_harvest_historyhasvineyard foreign key (Vineyard_Name) references VINEYARD(Vineyard_Name),
constraint fk_grape_harvest_historyhasgrape foreign key (Grape_Name) references GRAPE(Grape_Name))
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The constraint names are too long, maximum of 30 characters and these two are 32 and 34 characters long

fk_grape_harvest_historyhasvineyard
fk_grape_harvest_historyhasgrape